# How to create private variables within a namespace?

Tags: javascript, namespaces, private-members

For my web application, I am creating a namespace in JavaScript like so:

```
var com = {example: {}};
com.example.func1 = function(args) { ... }
com.example.func2 = function(args) { ... }
com.example.func3 = function(args) { ... }
```

I also want to create "private" (I know this doesn't exist in JS) namespace variables but am not sure what's the best design pattern to use.

Would it be:

```
com.example._var1 = null;
```

Or would the design pattern be something else?

Comment: By "great" do you mean "create"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript Namespace Declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504568/javascript-namespace-declaration)

Comment: @casablanca, no - my question is not a duplicate of what you linked too.

Comment: @Staceyl: The question I linked to has an example of how to create private variables within a namespace.

Comment: @Staceyl: first hit on google, searching for "javascript private member": http://www.crockford.com/javascript/private.html

Answer (score 9):

Douglas Crockford popularized so called [Module Pattern](http://ajaxian.com/archives/a-javascript-module-pattern) where you can create objects with "private" variables:

```
myModule = function () {

        //"private" variable:
        var myPrivateVar = "I can be accessed only from within myModule."

        return  {
                myPublicProperty: "I'm accessible as myModule.myPublicProperty"
                }
        };

}(); // the parens here cause the anonymous function to execute and return
```

But as you said Javascript doesn't truly have private variables and I think this is somewhat of a cludge, which break other things. Just try to inherit from that class, for example.

Answer (score 8):

Closures are frequently used like this to simulate private variables:

```
var com = {
    example: (function() {
        var that = {};

        // This variable will be captured in the closure and
        // inaccessible from outside, but will be accessible
        // from all closures defined in this one.
        var privateVar1;

        that.func1 = function(args) { ... };
        that.func2 = function(args) { ... } ;

        return that;
    })()
};
```

Comment: To add to this answer: This article describes a few different variations of the module pattern that you should consider. http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Answer (score 0):

After 7 years this might come quite late, but I think this might be useful for other programmers with a similar problem.

A few days ago I came up with the following function:

```
{
    let id    = 0;                          // declaring with let, so that id is not available from outside of this scope
    var getId = function () {               // declaring its accessor method as var so it is actually available from outside this scope
        id++;
        console.log('Returning ID: ', id);
        return id;
    }
}
```

This might only be useful if you are in a global scope and want to declare a variable that is not accessible from anywhere except your function that sets the value of id one up and returns its value.