# Put a variable between double quotes

Tags: javascript, function, variables, double-quotes

I have a small question:

I have a function in javascript.

```
var func = function(variable)
{
    result = variable;
}
```

If I call

```
func(rabbit);
```

I need the result to be "rabbit".

I cannot figure out how to put the variable between the two quotes.

Comment: It is not possible for a function to know the name of the variable passed by its caller.

Comment: @SLaks: ... as long as you don't parse a stacktrace with stringified functions :-)

Comment: @SLaks There's an horrible way to do it. See my answer

Comment: @lukedays: Key word being _horrible_.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `rabbit` is supposed to be a string:

```
func("rabbit");
```

If `rabbit` is actually a variable, then there's no way to do this because the variable (meaning the implementation's representation of a variable) isn't actually passed to the function, but rather its value is.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's an ancient way to retrieve the variable name.

```
var func = function(variable)
{
    console.log(variable); // outputs "white"
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.toString().match(/func\((.*?)\)/)[1]); // outputs "rabbit"
}

rabbit = 'white';

func(rabbit);
```

See it running http://jsfiddle.net/Q55Rb/

Comment: This will not work properly if the function is called twice.  Also, those properties are deprecated.

Comment: That's why I said it's an horrible and ancient way.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this

```js
function whatever(input) {
  return '\"' + input + '\"';
}
```

result should be in quotes

Answer (score 0):

I could not tell from your question whether you wanted "rabbit" to be the property name, or the value. So here is both:

```
var func = function(variable) {
    window[variable] = 'abc';    // Setting the variable as what is passed in
    window.result = variable;    // Normal
}

func('rabbit');    // Will set both window.rabbit to 'abc', and window.result to 'rabbit'
```

I wouldn't advise setting global variables, though. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I thought that was my problem. Now I'm pretty sure that's not it but I have no clue what it is then.

I have this in my function:

```
defaults = {title :{'pan':-1,'left':0,'volume':0.30,'top':111}};
```

Where title is a variable from the function. But as a result I get title in defaults instead of the actual title stored in the variable named title. Do you understand me?