# Insert image after a link

Tags: javascript

I have a large table that one column contains e-mail addresses (+/- 60), and I was told to add an e-mail icon after each address. I have been trying to use `anchors`,`.href` and `.indexof` to select the e-mail links, but have gotten no where (hence no code).

Can I get assistance on how to add `<img src="/a/path/email.jpg" alt="e-mail" />` if the link's `href` contains a `mailto` using **vanilla JavaScript**, *no jQuery*.

Comment: the image should be in the second column?

Comment: @adardesign no. The column is currently `<a>Name</a>`, I need to make it `<a>Name <img></a>`

Comment: FYI, `anchors` collection contains all anchor elements, i.e. `a` elements with `name` or / and `id` attribute, but not `href`. If you want to get `a`s with `href`, you can use `links` collection.

Comment: @RyanB, It dosn't have to be done via javascript.. See the CSS solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function you could use:

```
(function(allLinks)
{
    var i, imgHTML = '<img src="mail.png" alt="mail" />';
    for (i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++)
    {
        if (allLinks[i].getAttribute('href').indexOf('mailto') > -1)
        {//or allLinks.item(i).getAttribute('href').indexOf('mailto')
         //calling the item method is said to be faster, on most browsers
            allLinks[i].innerHTML += imgHTML;
        }
    }
}(document.getElementsByTagName('a')));
```

You can, of course turn this IIFE into a regular function, to be called on the load event or something...
Forked @adardesign's fiddle, [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/EkcgR/)

Comment: is the opening `(` needed? I don't see where you close it.

Comment: @RyanB: The very last bracket closes it. The opening `(` can be replaced with a bitwise NOT: `~` or bang `!`. This turns the function _definition_ into an expression. Google more about IIFE's (Immediately Invoked Function Expression), they're great fun! BTW, I'm sorry to say, but the accepted answer has an error in it, check my last comment there

Comment: Saw it, you added the () which cancelled the ) out, but I see you tweaked it. JSFiddle isn't working for me today.

Comment: @RyanB: It's dog-slow for me, too, but it's working. The fiddle I provided shows the link, and an img-not-found icon, so the code itself _is_ working. Just make sure that this code doesn't run prior to the links are loaded BTW (use it as the `window.onload` handler, or move this code to the bottom of the body and you're all right)

Answer (score 2):

### HTML

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="mailto:yankel@frieman.com">yankel@frieman.com</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### javascript

```
var table = document.getElementById("table"),
    links = table.getElementsByTagName("a"),
    linksLength = links.length,
    i = 0,
    link,
    href,
    text;

   for(; i>linksLength; i++){
      link = links[i];
      href=link.href,
      text = link.childNodes[0].nodeValue;

      if(href.indexOf("mailto:")){
         link.childNodes[0].nodeValue += text+ "<img src='path/to/email.png'>";
      }
 }
```

### See http://jsfiddle.net/adardesign/jJZCd/

Comment: I'll try this in a few, but is the semicolon aftfer the ( in the for loop a typo?

Comment: i am caching the variables to not pollute the global space  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted

Comment: @adardesign?? your fiddle is littered with global variables... I'm using an IIFE and thus not creating any global vars. Also, don't see the need for more than just three variables here. Lastly: your code is flawed: `if(href.indexOf('mailto:'))` will be false if the href value _starts with_ `mailto` => index: 0. If there is no `mailto`, then `indexOf` returns -1, which is a _truthy value_

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, you are totally right, i forgot to wrap with the IIFE

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to solve this problem

### CSS

```
a[href^="mailto:"]:after{
    content:url("path/to/email.png")
}
```

### See http://jsfiddle.net/adardesign/QWsVM/