# Can anyone tell how to attach an event handler to a hyperlink in Kendo UI Grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using MVVM framework(view/viewmodel). I have a hyperlinked field on one of the kendo grid columns. My requirement is that on clicking the hyperlink on the grid, viewmodel function  should call. I am trying to achieve this but not able to call. Please suggest any approach for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a template as:

```
template: '<a href="\\#" onclick="SayHello(this)">Click-me</a>',
```

And then define `SayHello` function as:

```
function SayHello(me) {
    alert("hello");
    var item = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataItem($(me).closest("tr"));
    console.log("item", item);
    item.sayGoodbye();
}
```

**NOTE:** That `SayHello` needs to be global.

Where `sayGoodbye` is defined in your model.

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2p3yH/

Comment: Since, i am using MVVM model. Is there any way to call viewmodel function directly?

Comment: Argh, inline event handlers! ;^) That's traditionally a code smell, but I think it's as close to The Easy, if not Right, Thing to do as you'll get. Otherwise, you have to apply the event handler in the grid's databound event -- **and then continue reapplying every time your row is re-rendered!** What a pain. Eg, w/ the popup editor, that means reapplying to the active row with each popup window's deactivate event, inserting code like `arguments[0].container.data("kendoWindow").bind("deactivate", function () { /*stuff*/});` in the `edit` event handler. Was hoping there'd be a better answer :(

Comment: @ruffin - didn't get your point. How can we achieve this without adding an inline event handler? especially in the case grid has multiple rows.

Comment: @SahilM. That was 6 years ago, so I'm not 100% in context. [Polluting the global context is usually something to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8862711/1028230), but this fix appeared, as I said earlier, "_as close to The Easy Thing to do as you'll get_". **Better would've been to be able to define that in a handler in the `grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({` definition** ([code from the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/2p3yH/)), but they don't (?) allow/expose it; [Telerik uses OnaBai's strategy in their own example](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-click-to-toggle-cell)

Comment: Oh, I have no idea this discussion had in so long past. Thanks, @ruffin for your attention to my comments. I am agreed with you and am curious about how can I tackle this thing without an inline hanlder. I will be tried it out in after-work hours :)

Comment: @SahilM. My guess is you can't, and I think OnaBai's solution is the practical one (I gave it a +1). If Telerik's own code is using a global handler ([it is](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-click-to-toggle-cell)), the best you can do, if anything, is probably just keep it in a child scope that contains the `$("#grid").kendoGrid` call **and** the event handler.