# JS - set a global variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I want to set a global variable via a set function but it always sets it to `undefined` value:

```
var name;
var setName = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}
```

Comment: `window.name` is a predefined property which might not be writable. Either use a different variable name or better, avoid global variables. Additionally, whether `this.name` works depends on how you are calling `setName`.

Comment: Are you actually passing a variable into the function, or expecting that the function will automagically populate the `name` parameter/argument with the `name` variable defined previously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you don't use `this`. (It could work but not necessarily. Why? Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope))

Just use:

```
var name;
var setName = function (aname) {
    name = aname;
}
```

Also make sure this code is **not** inside of another scope (function):

```
function foo() {
    // ...
    var name;
    var setName = function (aname) {
        name = aname;
    }
    // ...
}
```

In this case name would **not** be global and you would have to omit its declaration to make it global:

```
function foo() {
    // ...
    var setName = function (aname) {
        name = aname; // not it is global, if not defined in the visible scope
    }
    // ...
}
```

But this is a **bad** practice, so try to avoid polluting the [global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted). A variable is considered in the **global** namespace if:

- it has no `var` (`name = ...`, and there is no other visible local variable called `name`
- it is set on `window` (e.g. `window.name = ...`)

Comment: thanks,  I used global to express that it is outside the set function, I come from Java. I normally used this.name = name to set an intance variable in Java.

Comment: Despite the fact that javascript has 'java' at the beginning, javascript has nothing to do with java.  Not one thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
function(val){

    name = val
```

.......................

Answer (score 1):

First, window.name is a reserved property, and you should not use it.

Second, it's a good idea to namespace any global JavaScript, to avoid those types of issues or conflicts with third party libraries.

Here's a working example:

```
window.MyNamespace = {};
MyNamespace.name = '';
MyNamespace.setName = function(value) {
    MyNamespace.name = value;
};
MyNamespace.setName('hello');
MyNamespace.name; // "hello"
```

Based on your comment about this being in a module, this code will work:

```
(function(){ 
    app = {};  
    app.myPerson = (function(){ 
        var name;
        var setName = function(value) {
            name = value;
        };      
        setName('Charlie');
        console.log(name); // Charlie
    })();        
})();
```

Comment: sorry I used global to express that it is outside the set function, I come from Java. I normally used this.name = name to set an intance variable in Java.

Comment: Is your setName method supposed to be defined within a JavaScript object?

Comment: it is inside a module: (function(){ app.myPerson = (function(){ var name; })(); })();

Comment: Modules are intended to be self contained. If you need to access app.myPerson.name, you need to change myPerson from a module to an object.