# MVC 4 Ajax Requests - referencing a javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im making some ajax calls to return some partial views which are working fine when the scripts are written in the view.

Script code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    url: "@(Url.Action("ProjectPartial", "Project"))",
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        documentType: $('#DocumentType').val(),
        sectionName: $('#SectionName').val()
    }
})
.success(function (result) {
// Display the section contents.
$('#Projects').html(result);
})
.error(function (xhr, status) {
alert(xhr.responseText);
});
</script>
```

What i want to do is to store these in a javascript file called renderpartial.js so that i can add ajax calls to to one file and not write them into every view.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Ive tried putting

```
<script src="~/Scripts/RenderPartial.js"></script>
```

at the top of my page but all i get is the error function.

Comment: @JMB See my answer if you want to completely write all your js code in an external file and not in your view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you use inline razor syntax like `@(Url.Action(` you can't move it to js file

You can do it in either specifying url like

```
url: '/Project/ProjectPartial',
```

or in View.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var projectUrl="@(Url.Action("ProjectPartial", "Project"))"
</script>
```

in RenderParial.js

```
url: projectUrl,
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks. Hadn't even thought about the razor in the javascript file.

Comment: @JMB See my answer if you want to completely write all your js code in an external file and not in your view.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do it:

1. By using [AJAX.BeginForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.beginform%28v=vs.108%29.aspx). Using this, helps you not to write
   your javascript/jquery ajax calls but it is useful when you are
   doing something with only one form. When your form renders it then
   creates javascript for you which makes your view very clean.
2. I normally use a html5's `data-` attribute to read such kind of data
   that is easily available from the view in my js files. Because there
   are many cases where you want something to read from server in your
   view and you also want that data to be accessed in your javascript
   code, mainly in another view. Use razor syntac to put data in
   `data-` attributes like this:

   `//I assume you write this attribute in any control like this`

   `data-url="@(Url.Action("ProjectPartial", "Project")"`

   `//or if you want to write it in any html helper control as html attribute like this`

   `new { data_url="@(Url.Action("ProjectPartial", "Project")"}`

Now in your external js file you can read the url while making an ajax call. You can write as many data attributes as per your needs and make your of razor syntax to give you your data eg: type-post/get, contenttype,etc. and use like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('anyinput').attr('data-url');,
    contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
        documentType: $('#DocumentType').val(),
        sectionName: $('#SectionName').val()
    }
})
.success(function (result) {
// Display the section contents.
$('#Projects').html(result);
})
.error(function (xhr, status) {
alert(xhr.responseText);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about move the following to the js file.

```
function getPartial(UrlToGet) {
    $.ajax({
        url: UrlToGet,
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            documentType: $('#DocumentType').val(),
            sectionName: $('#SectionName').val()
        }
    })
    .success(function (result) {
        // Display the section contents.
        $('#Projects').html(result);
    })
    .error(function (xhr, status) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    });
}
```

And in your view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    getPartial('@(Url.Action("ProjectPartial", "Project"))');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A pattern I have used on recent projects to avoid polluting the global namespace is to encapuslate the function and configuration variables into an object-

```
var projectHelpers {
   config: {
       projectUrl: null
   },
   init: function() {
      //Do any page setup here...
   },
   getPartial: function() {
   if (projectHelpers.config.projectUrl) {
         $.ajax({   
            url: projectHelpers.config.projectUrl,
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                documentType: $('#DocumentType').val(),
                sectionName: $('#SectionName').val()
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(xhr.responseText); //Consider if console.log is more appropriate here
            },
            success: function (result) {    
                $('#Projects').html(result); // Display the section contents.
            }});
        } else {
            console.log("Missing project URL);
        }
   }
};
```

And then in the page-

```
projectHelpers.config.projectUrl = "@(Url.Action("ProjectPartial", "Project"))";
projectHelpers.init();
```

This helps encapsulate your code and is particularly useful when working with lots of external libraries to avoid variable collisions, as well as avoiding coding errors where you re-use a variable name and overwrite values.

See [What does it mean global namespace would be polluted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted) and [Using Objects to Organize Your Code](http://rmurphey.com/blog/2009/10/15/using-objects-to-organize-your-code/).