# How to produce divs using javascript and an XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently learning javascript and I'm attempting to create divs based on an xml file.

XML File - I realize the info is not correct(years).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Movies>
        <Movie>
                <Title>Independence Day</Title>
                <Year>2003</Year>
                <Rating>75</Rating>
        </Movie>
        <Movie>
                <Title>GroundHog Day</Title>
                <Year>1998</Year>
                <Rating>80</Rating>
        </Movie>

</Movies>
```

I'm then trying to produce an html file where I can format the divs with css.

html with JS

```
<html>
    <style type="text/css">
p {
    font-size: 14px;
}

div {
    border: 1px black solid;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;  
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

</style>

 <body>

 <script>
 xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlhttp.open("GET","movies.xml",false);
 xmlhttp.send();
 xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 


 var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Movie");
 for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
   { 
   document.write("<div><p>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</p><p>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Year")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</p><p>");
   document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Rating")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   document.write("</p></div");
   }

 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm getting data back, but I'm only producing one div with the data spilling out the bottom.  Why isn't this producing two divs - 1 per movie?

Comment: Don't use document.write.

Comment: Just to clarify what @bjb568 means by that, since the comment was pretty vague: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to learn things, I'm noting some points you should consider.

The style you write looks very oldschool, you should improve the following points:

- use JSON instead of XML. This protocol is more lightweight than XML and is much better to be processed by Javascript.
- don't use synchronous Ajax Calls
- don't use document write, create the elements directly and insert them afterwards.

My example does not include the ajax request, you can look at the according [MDN Docu on AJAX Calls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) to see, how it's properly done.

```
// the important stuff of your async ajax call:

xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      writeYourResultToTheDocument(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      console.error("An error occured!" + xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
};


function writeYourResultToTheDocument(response){

/* This code should is called when your request is complete */

// this is how it would look like in real:
// var movies = JSON.decode(response);
// since I don't do a real request, I take a "fake" result:
var movies =  [
        {   "Title" : "Independence Day",
            "Year": 2003,
            "Rating":75
        },
        {
            "Title":"GroundHog Day",
            "Year":1998,
            "Rating":80
        } 
    ];

 // Create Container Element for all movies
var container = document.createElement("div");

// declare every variable you use with "var" to *not* 
// create a global variable accidently
var movie,node;

// iterate over the result
for (var i = 0;i < movies.length;i++){
    //create a div for each movie
    movie = document.createElement("div");
    // insert all information
    for(el in movies[i]){
        node = document.createElement("p");
        node.innerHTML = el + " : " +movies[i][el];
        console.log(node);
        movie.appendChild(node);
    }
    container.appendChild(movie);
}
// finally, append the container to your document
document.body.appendChild(container);

}
```

And here how it could work: http://jsfiddle.net/xyLe4/

Comment: Since we're enumerating little tips, here's another: use `var` so that the global namespace doesn't get [polluted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a typo in your post or in your actual code, but you're missing the closing `>` on your last `div`. That very well could be what's causing the problem...

Comment: Thanks Dryden, always the simple thing, I have to wait 11 minutes to give you the answer.

Comment: You guys are fast, I had just found it after I wrote the code in just html without javascript, but I was already answered.  Good eyes

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.createElement('div')` to create the elements and append the childs to the `body`.

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

And a little working example: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/FKHb6/

Here is the same example with some Text content:

```
var Text = "Hello fine sir!"
var newDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
newDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Text));
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
```

See this in Action: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/FKHb6/1/