# "Outsource" recurring code into a function with parameters (js)

Tags: javascript, minimize, reducing

so i use one js file to load multiple html and js files whenever they are needed. I have a working code for plenty modules. In the example below you can see the first two modules. All of them look exactly the same. Now i want to "outsource" recurring code into a function with parameters so that the code-amount overall gets minimized. Since i have never done something like this before i could need some help (i am learning js at the moment). I would realy appreciate some help.

```
 //first module
 if (moduleID === "placeone") {
            var isLoaded = 0;
            if (isLoaded) {
                console.log("file already loaded");
                returnValue = new PlaceOneModule(id, moduleInitialData);
            }
            $("#placeone").load("html/modules/PlaceOneModule.html", function (response, status, xhr) {
                console.log("PlaceOneModule.html" + " " + status);
                $.getScript("js/modules/PlaceOneModule.js").done(function () {
                    console.log("PlaceOneModule.js geladen");
                    isLoaded = 1;
                    returnValue = new PlaceOneModule(id, moduleInitialData);
                }).fail(function () {
                    console.log("PlaceOneModule.js nicht geladen");
                });
            });
        }

    //second module
        if (moduleID === "placetwo") {
            var isLoaded = 0;
            if (isLoaded) {
                console.log("file already loaded");
                returnValue = new PlaceTwoModule(id, moduleInitialData);
            }
            $("#placetwo").load("html/modules/PlaceTwoModule.html", function (response, status, xhr) {
                console.log("PlaceTwoModule.html" + " " + status);
                $.getScript("js/modules/PlaceTwoModule.js").done(function () {
                    console.log("PlaceTwoModule.js geladen");
                    isLoaded = 1;
                    returnValue = new PlaceTwoModule(id, moduleInitialData);
                }).fail(function () {
                    console.log("PlaceTwoModule.js nicht geladen");
                });
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is rather complex to answer, as there are many things to account for.

```
var cache = {};

function module(name, target, done) {
    if (!(name in cache)) {
        return $(target).load('html/modules/' + name + '.html', function(response, status, xhr) {
            console.log(name + '.html ' + status);

            $.getScript('js/modules/' + name + '.js')
                .done(function() {
                    console.log(name + '.js geladen');
                    cache[name] = window[name];

                    done(null, cache[name]);
                })
                .fail(function() {
                    var message = name + '.js nicht geladen';

                    cache[name] = function() {
                        console.error(message);
                    };

                    done(message);
                });
        });
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        done(null, cache[name]);
    }, 0);
}
```

I'll try to explain my train of thought behind this:

- `var cache = {}` - you will need something to keep track of each individual module
- `function module(name, target, done) {`

  - `name` would be the base name of your module, e.g. `PlaceTwoModule`, this was already used consistently across the html and js files and the js function name
  - `target` would be the selector where the html file should be loaded
  - as one of the actions you take requires async operation, the entire functionality needs to become async, I introduce a callback (`done`) argument
- `if (!(name in cache))` - if the module is not yet cached, it requires some fetching, so the `load` is triggered first thing
- once the `load` completes, it will fire the `$.getScript`

  - if the `$.getScript` works out, the `name` will be assumed to be in `window` and a reference is stored in the `cache` variable, after that, the `done` callback is invoked (with the function as second argument).
  - if the `$.getScript` didn't work out, we add a function to the `cache`, which does nothing more than telling you it will not work, after that, the `done` callback is invoked (with an error as first argument).
- if the `name` did exist in the `cache`, we will be calling the `done` callback right after we exit the `module` function

So, how to use this?
It now boils down to calling the `module` function

```
module('#placeone', 'PlaceOneModule', function(error, PlaceModule) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  var instance = new PlaceModule(id, initial);

  // ...
}
```

I have used the common `function(error, value) {..}` signature for the callback function, which always has the error as first argument (allowing for other arguments to be added and made optional).

There are some caveats/assumptions worth mentioning:

- I have not provided a failsafe for preventing multiple loads of the same module (so it is the same as in your example) if earlier calls to `module` are still loading
- no matter what `target` you invoke `module` with, it will only load 'once' (well, see the previous line ;-) )
- I assume the loaded modules are in the global (`window`) scope in order to keep the example simple, keep in mind to not ['pollute the global scope'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted)

This has become a rather elaborate answer, I hope I explained every step involved sufficiently.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this possibly:

```
 var modules = [];
 modules.push({
   js: 'PlaceOneModule',
   id: 'placeone'
 });

 modules.push({
   js: 'PlaceTwoModule',
   id: 'placetwo'
 });

 var module = modules.filter(function(m) {
   return m.id === moduleID;
 });

 if (module) {
   var isLoaded = 0;
   if (!!window[module.js]) {
      console.log("file already loaded");
      returnValue = window[module.js];
   }

   $("#" + module.id).load("html/modules/" + module.js + ".html", function(response, status, xhr) {
     $.getScript("js/modules/" + module.js + ".js").done(function() {
        returnValue = new window[module.js](id, moduleInitialData);
     }).fail(function() {
        console.log("PlaceOneModule.js nicht geladen");
     });
   });
 }
```