# Accessing variables outside method call on an object without making them global (is it possible?)

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I found out I have two functions the share some some code so I decided to put it insied a *template* function:

```
function template(callback){
  var all, these, variables, are, used, inthe, callbackFunction;
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
      callback();
  }
}
function myFirstFunction(){
   //do something with all those variables
}
function mySecondFunction(){
   //do something else
}
```

So for each function I call `template(myFirstFunction)` and `template(mySecondFunction)`

Is there any way I can use all variables defined in *template* function from my functions without passing them by parameter?

---

#### EDIT:

My functions are actually methods of an object:

```
function MyObject(){

};
MyObject.prototype.template = function(){ 
  var all, these, variables, are, used, inthe, callbackFunction;
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
    callback();
  }};
MyObject.prototype.myFirstMethod = function(){ 
    this.template(function(){
        //doSomething with all those variables
    });
};
 MyObject.prototype.mySecondMethod = function(){ 
    this.template(function(){
        //doSomething else
    });
};
```

Comment: move them outside of template and you're done

Comment: You can either move them outside the template function and give them global scope or you can pass them as parameters.

Comment: You *could* set them as properties of `this` (or a context object) and then use `callback.call(this)`;

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the question. I now how scopes work. Is just that I am working with an object. And I was wondering if there was anything I could do other than putting them as global variables or passing them by parameter.  Apparently not

Comment: The best way to avoid *polluting the global namespace*, is to wrap everything inside a *self-executing function*. See my updated answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35752338/accessing-variables-outside-function-call/35752443#35752443) for how to do that for your object.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's stupid question I asked in a bad moment and it hurts my reputation whenever I have to share my stackoverflow account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself, I'd keep them in one place, without polluting the scope:

```
MyObject.prototype.template = function(){ 
    this.params = {all: '', these: '', variables: '', etc: ''}
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
        callback();
}};

MyObject.prototype.myFirstMethod = function(){ 
    var self = this;
    this.template(function(){
        console.log(self.params);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 8):

Woo! Scope problem! You need to declare the variables outside the local scope of the function. Like this:

```
var all, these, variables, are, used, inthe, callbackFunction;
function template(callback){
  for (var i=0; i<10; i++){
      callback();
  }
}
function myFirstFunction(){
   //do something with all those variables
}
function mySecondFunction(){
   //do something else
}
```

You can then access them in each of those functions. Scope can be tricky if you are new and I suggest reading up on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent [**polluting the global namespace**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted), you could wrap everything inside [**a self-executing function**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript) :

```
var MyObject = (function() {
    var all, these, variables, are, used, inthe, callbackFunction;
    
    var o = function() {
        // Do stuff
    };
    
    o.prototype.template = function(){ 
        for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
            callback();
        }
    };
      
    o.prototype.myFirstMethod = function(){ 
        this.template(function() {
            // Do something with all those variables
        });
    };

    o.prototype.mySecondMethod = function(){ 
        this.template(function() {
            // Do something else
        });
    };
    
    return o;
})();
```

---

#### Further reading :

[**Implementing Private and Protected Members in JavaScript**](http://Implementing%20Private%20and%20Protected%20Members%20in%20JavaScript)