# What is the difference between these two angular js controllers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

When declaring a controller I usually see these:

```
University.controller('ClassroomController', function($scope){
//do stuff
});
```

What's the difference of it compared to:

```
var classroomController = function ($scope){
//do stuff
}

University.controller('ClassroomController',['$scope',classroomController])
```

The tutorials doesn't seem to say whats the advantage of the second type of declaration.

Comment: The latter declares the `classroomController` symbol in whatever scope you're in which may not be desirable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted. It also supports Angular's DI annotation which will survive minification. Functionally, they're identical

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the reply! but I'm a bit confused with your answer, you say the latter may not be desirable but after reading the link you shared, from what I understood the latter declaration ensures garbage collection.

Comment: Hey @Phil thanks! I understand it now, the second declaration also minifies angular well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first syntax will break if you minify your js. Angular will for exemple try to find `$timeout` but will find `a`

To prevent that, you have to declare explicitly or inline your dependencies

Comment: I didn't understand this at first but after researching I can now relate to your answer. thanks so much!