# The business case for getElementById()

Tags: javascript, dom

It's my understanding that every modern browser, both desktop and mobile, surfaces elements with IDs to the global JavaScript namespace. Still, people all over the industry keep using `document.getElementById()` or its jQuery cousin `$("#TheID")`.

For cases that are not pathological (e. g. ID that matches another object in the global namespace), is there any reason for doing so, other than misplaced concern for backwards compatibility? How far back in time do you have to go so that it starts mattering?

EDIT: consider the following:

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="hidden" id="Foo" value="Hello world"/>
<input type="button" onclick="alert(Foo.value);" value="Press this"/>
</body>
</html>
```

It displays "Hello world" on MSIE on Windows, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari on Mac, Safari on iPad, Android browser, MSIE on Windows Phone... Why would anybody use `document.getElementById("Foo").value` instead?

Comment: I have no idea what you're actually asking.

Comment: What if external scripts that you include create variables with IDs that happen to be the same as element IDs on your page? You might not even notice, at first... Regarding `$("#TheID")`, the point of that is that it lets you use the various jQuery methods on the result.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted

Comment: Despite being borderline off-topic, upvoted due to this being the potential cause of many problems if used.

Comment: @Jecoms, the edit seems to be a little easier to understand.

Comment: @Bern Yeah, I see what he is suggesting now. Seems like a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: If you have literally a six-line html document with no script elements as shown in the edit then there isn't much that can go wrong, but a real-world page rarely looks that simple, and if the page is later expanded and script elements are added then one of the scripts might have a `Foo` variable of its own. Then what? It's best practice to keep global variables to a minimum, but still in the event that you decide you "need" one for something you shouldn't have to worry about whether the name might be the same as something in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

> For cases that are not pathological (e. g. ID that matches another object in the global namespace)…

Because literally *any* variable could be added to the global namespace, there is *no* case that are "not pathalogical".

> is there any reason for doing so, other than misplaced concern for backwards compatibility?

By convention we avoid introducing global variables that would otherwise conflict with existing global variables (e.x. we don't declare `var document` or `var setTimeout`). In fact, it's generally recommended that you avoid introducing *any* global variables at all by enclosing them in a scope somewhere.

If you were to do otherwise you will quickly run into maintenance issues. Maintenance issues that don't scale.

Consider the case where you have an element with `[id="question"]`. If you rely on the global reference of `question` to refer to that element, and someone else working on your project decides to introduce a `question.js` module elsewhere, you're going to have a *really* hard time debugging the issue.

The intent behind referencing `question` the DOM node will be unclear, and the means of accessing the element are equally unclear.

Furthermore, how do you handle the case where the ID changes? If you use `document.getElementById(...)` you will need to store a reference to the DOM node. If the ID changes, you'll only have to update the selector in one place.

If you start making use of the global reference to the DOM node, you'll need to update **all** the usages.

The reasons for avoiding global references to DOM nodes has *nothing* to do with compatibility, and everything to do with the fact that it's a terrible feature.

Comment: It's worth noting the readability factor as well. `foo` could be anything (string, int, object, etc) whereas document.getElementById("foo") will either be a DOM object or undefined.

Comment: @Bern, DOM node or `null` actually; but yes, the point that it serves as a data contract stands.

Comment: @Bern - It won't be undefined; it might be null. But you are correct about readability - even where the result is assigned to a variable you can trace that just by reading the JS, you don't have to also search through the HTML.

Comment: The answer assumes a certain structure of the page and the project - a huge page with numerous poorly written and poorly understood 3rd party dependencies, maintained by a team that doesn't communicate :) Still, point taken.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev, "a huge page" consider a large site with many interchangeable modules that may or may not exist. "that doesn't communicate" consider a large codebase that is constantly changing. The point is not that the team isn't communicating or that the pages are large. The point is that *the team doesn't have to waste time* sharing unnecessary trivial details and **the project is flexible** enough to undergo drastic changes with minimal negative effects.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason might be performance.  Referencing document only once is the preferred way, as far as I know.  See [10 Javascript Performance Boosting Tips from Nicholas Zakas](http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas) 1. Define local variables

In other words:

```
var doc = document;
var btn = doc.getElementById('myButton');
var img = doc.getElementById('myImage');
```

whereas

```
var btn = myButton;
var img = myImage;
```

has to lookup to document twice.