# How to access variables outside load method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to ajax and it is the first time I am using the jQuery's `load()` method. 
The example bellow doesn't work. The variable inside `doSomething()` is not defined (because of the asynchronously call I guess)

```
var x = jQuery("#div1 a"); // x is used in different parts of the code, not only for the doSomething function 

jQuery('.test').load(homeUrl, function() {
    doSomething();
};

function doSomething () {
     x.css('background-color', 'yellow');
}
```

So, I am doing like this (which is repetitive) and it works:

```
function doSomething () {
    var x =  jQuery("#div1 a");
    x.css('background-color', 'yellow');
}
```

But I would like to know if there is a better way of dealing with the variable or even if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: `this.x` - Seriously?

Comment: Although it is not very clear from the question, but you might be [polluting the global namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted#13352212)

Comment: @sid-m thank you:) As I am using that `x`variable in other functions it makes sense to me define it in the global object.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass x to the doSomething function like so:

var x = jQuery("#div1 a");

```
jQuery('.test').load(homeUrl, function() {
    doSomething(x);
};

function doSomething(x) {
    x.css('background-color', 'yellow');
}
```

Comment: Thank you!:) This is a good idea, but inside that function in reality I have lots of variables that are already defined before and in this situation I would have to use lots of parameters (I guess?).