# Load AJAX collections in order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to ensure, in JavaScript (jquery) that some actions are performed one after other, in an order.

Say, I need to load `schools` collection BEFORE loading `teachers`, in order to assing the `myTeacher.SchoolName = schools[myTeacher.SchoolId].name;`

The pseudo code bellow:

```
const studentsUrl='api/students', teachersUrl='api/teachers', schoolsUrl='api/schools';
let students = null, teachers = null, schools = null;

$(document).ready(function () {
    getSchools(); 
    getTeachers(); 
    getStudents(); 
});

function getSchools() {
    $.get(schoolsUrl, function (data) {
            window.schools = data;
        });
}

function getTeachers() {
    $.get(teachersUrl, function (data) {
            window.teachers = data;

            // >>> SHOULD BE SURE, SCHOOLS already loaded!!!
            $.each(teachers, function (key, item) {
                item.school = schools[item.schoolId].name;
            });
        });
}

function getStudents() {
    $.get(studentsUrl, function (data) {
            window.students = data;

            // >>> SHOULD BE SURE, TEACEHRS already loaded!!!
            $.each(students, function (key, item) {
                item.teacher = teachers[item.teacherId].name;
            });
        });
}
```

**PS.**

**Is there another way to assure order but the encapsulation of one function at the end of another?**

Comment: I think you could call getTeachers() function inside the success callback of getSchools()

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need all the results available and each request does not depend on the previous you can use [`jQuery.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/)

```js
let students = null;
let teachers = null;
let schools = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.when(
      getSchools(),
      getTeachers()
  ).done(function(shoolResults, teacherResults) {
      window.schools = shoolResults;
      window.teachers = teacherResults;
      handleTeachers();
      getStudents();
  });


  function getSchools() {
    return $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: schoolsUrl
    });
  }

  function getTeachers() {
    return $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: teachersUrl
    });
  }

  function handleTeachers() {
   $.each(teachers, function (key, item) { 
     item.school = schools[item.schoolId].name;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: in fact, I need to obtain the schools, then the teachers(having school-id), and only then the students(having a teacher-id), but I see the principle... ) thanks!

Comment: I am afraid the $when will not assure in that example that schoolResults will be loaded BEFORE teachers....

Comment: @Serge it will assure that both have loaded when the`.done` is called, and inside the `done` you have, as arguments, the results of each call.

Comment: but I need to ensure schools loaded *before* teachers, here we don't have an exact order (schools=> teachers), but an assurance both are loaded (we don't know the order)

Answer (score 1):

As others already suggested you can chain requests. 
I made few changes to your code.

1. Added [Strict Mode](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp) it helps to prevent bugs
2. The code wrapped in [IFFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) in order to prevent  [global pollution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted)

If all apis belong to the same server you can process all this data on server side
and return one filled json.
in this way your server will do a little extra work on constructing this json but in other hand you will make only one ajax request instead of 3.
This will work faster and you can cache this json for some time

Code for the first solution

```
(function () {

'use strict';
const studentsUrl = 'api/students';
const teachersUrl = 'api/teachers';
const schoolsUrl = 'api/schools';

let students = null;
let teachers = null;
let schools = null;

var scoolData = {
    schools: null,
    teachers: null,
    students: null
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    getSchools().then(function (schools) {
        scoolData.schools = schools;
        getTeachers().then(function (teachers) {
            scoolData.teachers = teachers;
            $.each(scoolData.teachers, function (key, item) {
                item.school = scoolData.schools[item.schoolId].name;
            });
        });
    });
});

function getSchools() {
    return $.get(schoolsUrl);
}

function getTeachers() {
    return $.get(teachersUrl,
        function (result) {
            scoolData.teachers = result;

            // >>> SHOULD BE SURE, SCHOOLS already loaded!!!
            $.each(teachers, function (key, item) {
                item.school = scoolData.schools[item.schoolId].name;
            });
        });
}
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them in order (though I'm not sure I understand why, since you retrieve all schools/teachers/students anyway), you can simply do this.

**Note**: `get*` functions are dummies in the following sample. Instead, just return the result of `$.get` calls from them:

```js
function getSchools() {
  return Promise.resolve({1: {name: 'school1'}});
}

function getTeachers() {
  return Promise.resolve({1: {name: 'teacher1', schoolId: 1}});
}

function getStudents() {
  return Promise.resolve({1: {name: 'student1', teacherId: 1}});
}

(async () => {
  const schools = await getSchools();
  const teachers = await getTeachers();
  const students = await getStudents();

    // Alternative for the $.each code
  Object.values(teachers).forEach(teacher => teacher.school = schools[teacher.schoolId].name);
  Object.values(students).forEach(student => student.teacher = teachers[student.teacherId].name);
  
  console.log(schools, teachers, students);
})();
```

Another note: this is ES8 code, I'll post a non async/await version if you need to support older browsers and can't use a transpiler like Babel.

**Non ES8-dependent code**:

```js
function getSchools() {
  return Promise.resolve({1: {name: 'school1'}});
}

function getTeachers() {
  return Promise.resolve({1: {name: 'teacher1', schoolId: 1}});
}

function getStudents() {
  return Promise.resolve({1: {name: 'student1', teacherId: 1}});
}

let schools = null, teachers = null, students = null;

getSchools().then(_schools => {
  schools = _schools;
  return getTeachers();
}).then(_teachers => {
  teachers = _teachers;
  return getStudents();
}).then(_students => {
  students = _students;

  for (var _ in teachers) {
    teachers[_].school = schools[teachers[_].schoolId].name;
  }
  for (var _ in students) {
    students[_].teacher = teachers[students[_].teacherId].name
  }

  console.log(schools, teachers, students);
});
```

Comment: the get functions could take some params... but i supposed to fill-in "global" collections, then use them inside teachers and students functions

Comment: also, as is, the get functions code does not return anything.. i don't know if await is ok with it

Comment: @Serge Just return the result of `$.get` each time, and remove the `$.each` code from within the functions themselves. Put them after the three await's.

Comment: @Serge I've added a working snippet with dummy `get*` functions. See my comments.

Comment: I see the principle... perhaps is OK for Chrome... could you for the completion post an example that will work for the most of the browsers?

Comment: is not really clear for me, how can I replace `Promise.Resolve` with get... should it be `return $.get(schoolsUrl)`... don't think so...

Comment: @Serge Yes it is, just do that. `$.get` returns a `Promise` equivalent.

Comment: yes, but does the $get return the data, for `const schools = await getSchools();` if `getSchools{ return $get(schoolsUrl); }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181774/discussion-between-jeto-and-serge).

Answer (score 0):

Call `getTeachers();` when `getSchools();` return success or complete, success preferred since complete runs if there's an error..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this one.

```
 getSchools().done(function(data){
      var someId = data.findThatId;
      getTeachers(someId);
 });
```

You will need to return data from ajax call to get `data` in `done`.

Comment: is it something like the @Gabriele Petrioli's answer?

Comment: it is the exact same.

Comment: but "when" is not needed?

Comment: you can use multiple promises inside `$.when`

Comment: what about `function (result) {` should I remove it from inside the functions returning a promise?

Comment: i dont get your question

Comment: I use `$get(url, success)`, but should I use just `return $get(url);`

Comment: You can return value inside `$.get`, but better to use it your way. `return $.get(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You may load them asynchronously but you have to wait until both calls are finished.

To achieve this, add `return` before your ajax calls and combine the results in your ready function (not in the success handler of the teachers call):

```
let schoolsPromise = getSchools();
let teachersPromise = getTeachers();
$.when(schoolsPromise, teachersPromise)
  .then((schools, teachers) => {
    $.each(teachers, (key, item) => {
      item.school = schools[item.schoolId].name;
    });
  });
```

Comment: should I add `return` and keep `function(result)` with the $get call? Gabriele Petrioli removed it from the functions...

Comment: similar to schools, students have the teacher-id, so I need to load first teachers... then students

Comment: If you need to do something (which doesn't need the other calls' results) to an ajax call result, the success handler is okay. At least you have to store some of the objects but you may also do that in an additional `.then(...)` callback in the ready function. If course you can reuse the promise variables by adding another `$.when(studentsPromise, teachersPromise).then(...)` which combines the data as desired.