# Can I transfer the scope of a function to another when calling it?

Tags: javascript

```
function parent() {
    let name = 'joe';
    printName();

    function printName() {console.log(name)}
}
```

this works, but i want to move printName outside of the other function.

```
function parent() {
    let name = 'joe';
    printName();
}
function printName() {console.log(name)}
```

but this does not work, since name is stuck inside the parent function. Is there a way to send the current scope of parent to printName when I call that function on line 3? something like .bind but for all variables not just `this`

Comment: No, it's not possible. Make `name` a parameter to the function.

Comment: You may want to look into [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) as a possible alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to send the current scope of parent to printName when I call that function on line 3? something like .bind but for all variables not just `this`

No. But here are two alternatives:

1. Use functional programming techniques: create a `name` parameter for the `printName` function and provide the name argument when invoking it:

```js
function printName (name) {
  console.log(name);
}

function parent () {
  let name = 'joe';
  printName(name);
}

parent(); // logs "joe"
```

2. Initialize an object that is in scope for both functions and mutate its properties. In this second approach, both functions are [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) because they depend on the reference to `obj` being available when they are invoked:

```js
const obj = {};

function printName () {
  console.log(obj.name);
}

function parent () {
  obj.name = 'joe';
  printName();
}

parent(); // logs "joe"
```

The second approach is conceptually like assigning properties to the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Global_object), but it avoids [global scope pollution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8862665/438273).